# How to include composer to phpbrowserbox?

Tags: php, composer-php, exe

How to include composer to phpbrowserbox?
https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpbrowserbox/files/

Comment: This question is a bit too general. You should at least include the ways you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

0) Downlaod   phpbrowserbox  source
https://github.com/dhtml/phpbrowserbox

1) download composer.phar from Manual download:
https://getcomposer.org/download/
and move this composer.phar to `"...\support\inetpub"` directory. In my case it was 
`C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\inetpub`

2) Create `compose.json` file in the ame directory. In my case it was  `C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\inetpub\composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "RecB2own",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "My Recipes",

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "src\\core\\" : "src/core/",
            "Rec\\RecipBundle\\Entity\\" : "src/Rec/RecipBundle/Entity/",
            "Rec\\RecipBundle\\Controller\\" : "src/Rec/RecipBundle/Controller/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/core/App.php",
            "src/core/View.php",
            "src/core/Controller.php"
        ]
    },    

    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.1"
    }   

}
```

3) Change `php.ini` in `C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\php`  marked as configuration file by removing infront ";"

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

4) Start commnad line with cmd command

4a) Change to `"...\support\inetpub"` directory. In my case it was
`C:\Users\gintare>cd C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\inetpub`

4b) Run composer. In my case it was

C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\inetpub>`C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\php\php  C:\Users\gintare\Downloads\support\inetpub\composer.phar  install`